# Apache: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error - WooCommerce

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4, wordpress

I have a woocommerce site. I have a recursive error in the Apache error.log:

```
[Mon Nov 02 17:04:58.723578 2015] [core:error] [pid 2922] [client 172.31.12.207:19044] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: https://gremyo.com/wp-content/themes/bishop/woocommerce/style.css
[Mon Nov 02 17:04:58.812460 2015] [core:error] [pid 2928] [client 172.31.12.207:19045] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: https://gremyo.com/wp-content/themes/bishop/woocommerce/style.css
[Mon Nov 02 17:13:58.112870 2015] [core:error] [pid 3100] [client 172.31.27.233:39991] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Mon Nov 02 17:13:58.430530 2015] [core:error] [pid 2905] [client 172.31.27.233:39992] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Mon Nov 02 17:23:23.530340 2015] [core:error] [pid 3205] [client 172.31.11.223:48080] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://gremyo.com/wp-signup.php?new=publisherweb
[Mon Nov 02 17:25:08.819153 2015] [core:error] [pid 3244] [client 172.31.27.233:40380] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: https://muyinteresante.gremyo.com/
```

I have seen the error happens when a javascript fires up a window with the detailed images (referer ...style.css) in the single product page. The google-chrome console registers these errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) https://gremyo.com/wp-content/themes/bishop/fonts/WooCommerce.woff 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) https://gremyo.com/wp-content/themes/bishop/fonts/WooCommerce.ttf
```

I have this in the .htaccess file, related to chrome errors.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

However, the error appear in more places of the site (I haven't identified them yet).

The reason to investigate this is the site doesn't load properly CSS in some product pages when they're cached. I use wp-super-cache and autoptimize plugins.

Do you have an idea to help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod\_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Answer (score 0):

Focus on "https://gremyo.com/wp-content/themes/bishop/fonts/WooCommerce.woff" request. This request is not served (error 500) and is probably the source of recursive error.

Check content of themes/bishop/fonts/, probably there is an .htaccess file there or maybe another .htaccess in one of parents directories.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set `LogLevel debug` in your configuration files
2. In the log you should see which URL is really causing the problem
3. Review your `.htaccess` for configs related to that URL.

Possible helpful links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850845/request-exceeded-the-limit-of-10-internal-redirects-due-to-probable-configuratio
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490215/apache-htaccess-request-exceeded-the-limit-of-10-internal-redirects-due-to-pro
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723981/request-exceeded-the-limit-of-10-internal-redirects-due-to-probable-configuratio